# snap.svg selectAll class issue with mutiple classes

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Doing some work in snap.svg and got issues with selectAll.

The function returns the correct paths if the path ONLY has the class switch, but if i add another class after switch the functions does no longer return any paths.

How do i format my argument so that selectAll returns the path even if other classes are present on the same path.

My usage

```
var zones = svg_layer.selectAll( 'path[class=switch]' );
```

This will return the path.

```
<path class="switch" fill="none" stroke="#009640" stroke-width="0.7087" d="
    M236.6,75c0-14.1,1,75z"></path>
```

When i add the class **used** the path is no longer returned.

```
<path class="switch used" fill="none" stroke="#009640" stroke-width="0.7087" d="
    M236.6,75c0-14.1,1,75z"></path>
```

http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.selectAll

Very happy for all help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snap function used querySelectorAll to return the nodelist.

Simply writing it like this solved my issue.

```
var zones = svg_layer.selectAll( 'path.switch' );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll